# How to reset the window in Tkinter based on a radio button selection

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to create a Python Tkinter programme that resets the window based on a radio button selection. So that the user sees the correct input field(s) for the radio button selected. In the example below the user select a radiobutton to enter a band name (e.g. Duran Duran) or artist name in to 2 fields (e.g. Michael Kiwanuka).

The problem is that the tk windows just keep spawning new windows.

What I really want to understand is how can I create a window, add some widgets and then change the widgets depending on the radio button choice.

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("My Project")
# parent_window.geometry("width_size x height_size + x_position + y_position")
window.minsize(width=850, height=550)
window.configure(bg="#bcbcbc")

def make_window():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("My Project")
    # parent_window.geometry("width_size x height_size + x_position + y_position")
    window.minsize(width=850, height=550)
    window.configure(bg="#bcbcbc")
    radio_state = IntVar()
    radiobutton1 = Radiobutton(text="Artist is a Band", value=1, variable=radio_state, command=artist_band)
    radiobutton2 = Radiobutton(text="Artist is a Person", value=2, variable=radio_state, command=artist_person)
    radiobutton1.pack()
    radiobutton2.pack()

def reset_all():
    window.destroy()
    make_window()

def artist_band():
    print("Artist is a Band")
    reset_all()
    make_window()
    inp_band_name = Entry(borderwidth=2, background="white", width=40, fg="red")
    inp_band_name.insert(END, string="")
    inp_band_name.pack()

def artist_person():
    print("Artist is a Person")
    reset_all()
    make_window()
    inp_first_name = Entry(borderwidth=2, background="white", width=25, )
    inp_first_name.insert(END, string="")
    inp_first_name.pack()
    inp_second_name = Entry(borderwidth=2, background="white", width=25, )
    inp_second_name.insert(END, string="")
    inp_second_name.pack()

radio_state = IntVar()
radiobutton1 = Radiobutton(text="Artist is a Band", value=1, variable=radio_state, command=artist_band)
radiobutton2 = Radiobutton(text="Artist is a Person", value=2, variable=radio_state, command=artist_person)
radiobutton1.pack()
radiobutton2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

window = Tk() should be the only one in the program. It can be minimized or hidden, but when it is closed, the program also ends. Child windows are created using Toplevel().

```
from tkinter import *



def make_window(text):
    win = Toplevel()
    win.title(text)
    # parent_window.geometry("width_size x height_size + x_position + y_position")
    win.minsize(width=850, height=550)
    win.configure(bg="#bcbcbc")
    name = Entry(win, borderwidth=2, background="white", width=40, fg="red")
    name.insert(END, string=text)
    name.pack()
    window.iconify()

def reset_all():
    window.destroy()
    make_window()

def artist_band():
    print("Artist is a Band")
    make_window('Artist is a Band')


def artist_person():
    print("Artist is a Person")
    make_window('Artist is a Person')


window = Tk()
window.title("My Project")
# parent_window.geometry("width_size x height_size + x_position + y_position")
window.minsize(width=850, height=550)
window.configure(bg="#bcbcbc")

radio_state = IntVar()
radiobutton1 = Radiobutton(window, text="Artist is a Band", value=1, variable=radio_state, command=artist_band)
radiobutton2 = Radiobutton(window, text="Artist is a Person", value=2, variable=radio_state, command=artist_person)
radiobutton1.pack()
radiobutton2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[Windows and Dialogs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html)